# Beautiful soup not getting all data in scraping weblink in jupyter and also not getting tags below ::before and ::after tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrap dimensions(height and width you can see in weblink https://www.cb2.com/jaxx-round-red-marble-side-table-tall/s265076    but its not getting tags of height and width.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.cb2.com/jaxx-round-red-marble-side-table-tall/s265076'
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
htmlContent = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlContent,'html.parser')
dimensions = soup.find_all('p',attrs = {'class':'dimension-text text-md-reg'})
print(dimensions)
```

I tried [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) but its not getting all tags.

Comment: Could you share a image for what you want to crawl @IbtesamAhmed

Comment: *Always and first of all, take a closer look at your soup to see if all the expected ingredients are in place.* What do you find in your `soup` / `response`?

Answer (score 2):

The data is dynamically loaded by JS, but it's embedded in the source HTML.

For example, you can get the height with this:

```py
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.cb2.com/jaxx-round-red-marble-side-table-tall/s265076"
headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
}
data = (
    BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, "lxml")
    .find_all("script", type="application/ld+json")
)
print(json.loads(data[-2].string)["height"]["value"])
```

Output:

```
17.5
```